# The request entity's media type 'application/xml' is not supported for this resource

Tags: c#, .net, xml, api, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to pass XLIFF content in the parameter of following function, I am getting error:

```
public IHttpActionResult ProcessSmartlingTranslation([FromBody]xliff xliff)
       {
           return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Any object");
       }
```

> {  "message": "The request entity's media type 'application/xml' is
>   not supported for this resource.",  "exceptionMessage": "No
>   MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'xliff' from
>   content with media type 'application/xml'.",  "exceptionType":
>   "System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException",  "stackTrace": "   at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent
>   content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger
>   formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync(HttpContent content,
>   Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger
>   formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)" }

How would i solve the issue?

Complete code is below:

```
// <summary>
   /// XliffModel created
   /// </summary>
   public class xliff
   {
       /// <summary>
       /// file getter setter method
       /// </summary>
       public string file { get; set; }
       /// <summary>
       /// body getter setter method
       /// </summary>
       public string body { get; set; }
   }
   /// <summary>
   /// Web api for smartling translation processing
   /// </summary>
   /// <seealso cref="ApiController" />
   public class SmartlingController : ApiController
   {
       #region Public Methods

       /// <summary>
       /// Get or insert blog comments which is approved based on blogs
       /// </summary>
       /// <remarks> Get or insert blog comments which is approved based on blogs</remarks>
       /// <param name="message">The comment.</param>
       /// <response code="200">Get approved blog comments</response>
       /// <response code="404">Not found</response>
       /// <returns>IHttpActionResult</returns>
       [Route("api/smartling/ProcessSmartlingTranslation")]
       [VersionedRoute("", 1)]
       [ResponseType(typeof(HttpResponseMessage))]
       [HttpPost]
       public IHttpActionResult ProcessSmartlingTranslation([FromBody]xliff xlf)
       {
           return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Any object");
       }
       #endregion
   }
```

Comment: what is your request content type

Comment: xliff format it is  application/xliff+xml   or application/xliff+xml

Answer (score 0):

when I check default xml media file formatter, it is look like..

[image]

I do not know what will happen, if adding manual. may be need customize serialization..

```
            config.Formatters.XmlFormatter
            .SupportedMediaTypes
            .Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xliff+xml"));
```